# Creating bash function to convert iso to img on mac?

Tags: macos, bash

I've converted .iso files to .img on mac using hdiutil before, but I'm trying to make an alias for it in my .bashrc.

I want it to take to flags -if and -of as input and output files, and if no flags are present to just convert to a default output file.

Here's my code:

```
function mkimg {
if [ "$1" == "-if=" && "$3" == "-of=" ]; then
    hdiutil convert "$2" -format UDRW -o "$4";
    "$5" = "$4.img";
    "$4" = "$4.dmg";
    mv "$4" "$5";
    echo "Completed. New file saved to: $5";
  else
     hdiutil convert "$1" -format UDRW -o ~/Desktop/still\ converting.img;
     mv ~/Desktop/still\ converting.img.dmg ~/Desktop/newimg.img;
     echo "Completed. New file saved to: ~/Desktop/newimg.img";
  fi
}
```

When I run it it gives me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you Cyrus, that solved the issue :)
For any time travelers with similar problems, use -a instead of &&

Comment: Using `&&` is more portable but you need `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Cyrus and Etan says in its comments, there is an error in the statement:

```
if [ "$1" == "-if=" && "$3" == "-of=" ]; then
```

that must be:

```
if [ "$1" == "-if=" -a "$3" == "-of=" ]; then
```

or better:

```
if [ "$1" == "-if=" ] && [ "$3" == "-of=" ]; then
```

Note to readers: this answer is only for stackoverflow cleanup, in order question doesn't appears as zero answers. Community wiki is active, votes doesn't increase/decreases reputation of the author.